# How to test a Service in Angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I know how to test a controller in [**Angular 1.3**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api), but my question here is how to test a service without calling from any controller.

I tried to follow examples but nothing happen.

**Test**

```
describe("Testing my service", function () {
    var myService;

    beforeEach(module("core"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value("myService", myService);
    }));

    it("get value", function () {
      var value = myService.getValue();
      expect(value).toEqual(2);
    });
  });
```

**Result**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module core due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

Thank you

Comment: And your service is?..

Comment: in the example I write myService as a name of my service

Comment: seems like you module has `ui.router` dependency which you haven't referred on `test.html` page